# CoreGraphic - display umlaut mark on an i

Tags: iphone, core-graphics

I'm to trying to display an umlaut mark on an i in my CoreGraphics function: ï. 
I tried to use it's unicode representation (ï), but I don't manage to get it right.

here is my code:

```
void drawColorString(CGContextRef ctx, NSString *text, UIColor *color, CGPoint pos){
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    [color setFill];
    CGContextSelectFont(ctx, "Georgia-BoldItalic", 14, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextFill);
    CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(ctx, xform);
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(ctx, pos.x, pos.y, [text UTF8String], text.length);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

it works very well for regular strings, but I get a square for each special char...

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.
R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing text in Quartz sucks. One reason is that it doesn't support Unicode: Your choices are plain old ASCII and MacRoman. You might be able to do it by looking up the glyphs for the characters, but that's not fun at all and I bet there are some easy ways to get it wrong.

You can draw a ï in MacRoman easily enough, but a far better solution is to switch to Core Text.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
I'm not familiar with Core Text but I read it require iOS 3.2 and I need to target iOS 3.0 for my application. That's why I'm stuck with Quartz.
I would be more than pleased to switch to something simpler...

Comment: Ok you were right. I quit Quartz, and just used drawInRect:withFont: method from NSString